# toggle required on textfields when checkboxes are checked

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox, toggle, textfield

I set all my check-boxes checked when any of the check-boxes in a table is clicked. Now I need to set all text fields to required when the check-boxes are checked and remove required when all check-boxes are not checked.

With this code I check all check-boxes.How do I toggle required on the text-fields fields?

```
$('.checkAll').click(function (e) {
    $(this).closest('table').find(':checkbox').prop('checked', this.checked);
})
```

Comment: Have you tried finding the textfields and doing prop('required', true) ?

Comment: which jquery version do you use ?

Answer (score 1):

Just insert this in your code.

```
$("input:text").prop('required',true);
```

Example:

```
$('.checkAll').click(function (e) {
    $(this).closest('table').find(':checkbox').prop('checked', this.checked);
    $("input:text").prop('required', true);
})
```

Or you can replace `"input:text"` with a class that is on each textfield that you need to be required

Hope this helps!